# Permission to specific field in Django admin panel

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-admin

I have a model in Django that I want to add instances to it from the admin panel.

I have few users that will have access to the admin panel to create new posts to the model and I have 2 questions:

1. It is possible to detect witch user is in the panel to auto-detect the field "Author"? (See the red rectangle in the picture)
2. Can I disable the option to a specific user to mark the "Published" field as true? (See the green rectangle in the picture)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For pre-populating fields you can override [get_form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_form) method:

```
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    form = super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
    form.base_fields['author'].initial = request.user
    return form
```

For disabling fields you can override...[get_readonly_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_readonly_fields) as well:

```
class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    readonly_fields = ('whatever', ) # whatever fields you have by default
    limited_fiels = ('published', )

    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        if request.user.groups.filter(name='YourPermissionGroupName').exists():
            return self.limited_fiels
        return super().get_fieldsets(request, obj=obj)
```

You may need to override [get_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_fields) as well to remove `published` from changable fields list as well.